# Комментарий к коду, программа Гонки

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно описать комментарий коду Гонки с примером!

В заранее благодарен!

```
package dragracing;

/*
Методы интерфейса CarInterface
 */

public interface CarInterface {

    public int getId();

    public void setId(int id);

    public String getDriver();

    public void setDriver(String driver);

    public String getManufacturer();

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer);

    public int getMaxSpeed();

    public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed);

    public String getModel();

    public void setModel(String model);

    public int getVelocity();

    public void setVelocity(int velocity);

    public long getCurrentSpeed();

    public void setCurrentSpeed(long currentSpeed);

    public long getRunDistance();

    public void setRunDistance(long runDistance);

    public int getRunTime();

    public void setRunTime(int runTime);
}

/*
Поля класса Car интерфейса CarInterface
 */

class Car implements CarInterface {

    private int id;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private int velocity;
    private int maxSpeed;
    private long currentSpeed = 0;
    private long runDistance = 0;
    private int runTime = 0;
    private String driver;

/*
Конструктор класса Car с входными параметрами элемента класса Car
 */

    public Car(Car car) {
        this.id = car.id;
        this.manufacturer = car.manufacturer;
        this.model = car.model;
        this.velocity = car.velocity;
        this.maxSpeed = car.maxSpeed;
        this.driver = car.driver;
        this.currentSpeed = 0;
        this.runDistance = 0;
        this.runTime = 0;
    }

/*
Конструктор класса Car с входными параметрами
 */

    public Car(int id, String manufacturer, String model, int velocity, int maxSpeed, String driver) {
        this.id = id;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.driver = driver;
    }

/*
Метод getId возращающий значения id
 */

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

/*
Метод setId невозращающий значения id
 */

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

/*
Метод getDriver возращающий значения driver
 */

    public String getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

/*
Метод setDriver невозращающий значения driver
 */

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

/*
Метод getManufacturer возращающий значения manufacturer
 */

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return this.manufacturer;
    }

/*
Метод setManufacturer невозращающий значения manufacturer
 */

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

/*
Метод getMaxSpeed возращающий значения maxSpeed
 */

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return this.maxSpeed;
    }

/*
Метод setMaxSpeed невозращающий значения maxSpeed
 */

    public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

/*
Метод getModel возращающий значения model
 */

    public String getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }

/*
Метод setModel невозращающий значения model
 */

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

/*
Метод getVelocity возращающий значения velocity
 */

    public int getVelocity() {
        return this.velocity;
    }

/*
Метод setVelocity невозращающий значения velocity
 */

    public void setVelocity(int velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

/*
Метод getCurrentSpeed возращающий значения currentSpeed
 */

    public long getCurrentSpeed() {
        return this.currentSpeed;
    }

/*
Метод setCurrentSpeed невозращающий значения currentSpeed
 */

    public void setCurrentSpeed(long currentSpeed) {
        this.currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
    }

/*
Метод getRunDistance возращающий значения runDistance
 */

    public long getRunDistance() {
        return this.runDistance;
    }

/*
Метод setRunDistance невозращающий значения runDistance
 */

    public void setRunDistance(long runDistance) {
        this.runDistance = runDistance;
    }

/*
Метод getRunTime возращающий значения runTime
 */

    public int getRunTime() {
        return this.runTime;
    }

/*
Метод setRunTime невозращающий значения runTime
 */

    public void setRunTime(int runTime) {
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
}
```

Второй класс

```
package dragracing;

/*
импорт библиотек
 */

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/*
Поля класса Dragracing с типизированными списакми
 */

public class Dragracing {

    private static Map<Integer, Car> cars = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();

/*
Статическая константа trackLength
 */

    private static final int trackLength = 402;

/*
Статическая метод setCars невозращающий не какого значения
 с описанием значений и названий
 */

    private static void setCars() {
        cars.put(1, new Car(1, "Toyota", "Celica", 6, 250, "Alex"));
        cars.put(2, new Car(2, "Dodge", "Viper", 7, 310, "Steve"));
        cars.put(3, new Car(3, "Porsche", "911", 9, 320, "Martin"));
        cars.put(4, new Car(4, "Dodge", "Challenger", 9, 250, "Andrew"));
        cars.put(5, new Car(5, "Toyota", "MR2", 5, 250, "Jim"));
        cars.put(6, new Car(6, "Honda", "NSX", 8, 280, "Hiroki"));
        cars.put(7, new Car(7, "Chevrolet", "Camaro", 8, 270, "Ricky"));
        cars.put(8, new Car(8, "Nissan", "GTR", 8, 310, "Kito"));
        cars.put(9, new Car(9, "Lamborghini", "Countach", 8, 300, "Linda"));
        cars.put(10, new Car(10, "VAZ", "2107", 8, 200, "Vasiliy"));
    }

/*
Статическая метод refresh невозращающий не какого значения
 с входными параметрами
 с условным оператором if
 */

    private static void refresh(Car car, int time) {
        long maxSpeed = Math.round(car.getMaxSpeed()/3.6);
        long curSpeed = Math.round(car.getVelocity() * time);
        if(curSpeed > maxSpeed)
            curSpeed = maxSpeed;
        car.setRunDistance(car.getRunDistance() + curSpeed > trackLength ? trackLength : car.getRunDistance() + curSpeed);
        car.setCurrentSpeed(Math.round(curSpeed*3.6));
    }

/*
Статическая метод main невозращающий не какого значения
 с входными параметрами с исключительной ситуацией throws InterruptedException
 так же с типизированным списком
 с циклом for
 переменной boolean
 с циклом while
 c условным оператором if
 */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        HashMap<Integer, Car> results = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();
        setCars();
        int runNum = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < cars.size(); i++) {
            Car left = new Car(cars.get(i++));
            Car right = new Car(cars.get(i));
            boolean run = true;
            System.out.println("Run " + runNum + ": " + left.getDriver() + " on " + left.getManufacturer() + " " + left.getModel() + " vs. " + right.getDriver() + " on " + right.getManufacturer() + " " + right.getModel());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Ready!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Steady!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("GO!");
            int seconds = 0;
            while(run) {
                System.out.println("Run " + runNum + ": " + left.getDriver() + " on " + left.getManufacturer() + " " + left.getModel() + " vs. " + right.getDriver() + " on " + right.getManufacturer() + " " + right.getModel());
                System.out.println(left.getDriver() + ": " + left.getRunDistance() + " meters, " + left.getCurrentSpeed() + " km/h");
                System.out.println(right.getDriver() + ": " + right.getRunDistance() + " meters, " + right.getCurrentSpeed() + " km/h");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seconds++;
                if(left.getRunTime() == 0)
                    refresh(left, seconds);
                if(right.getRunTime() == 0)
                    refresh(right, seconds);
                if(left.getRunTime() > 0 && right.getRunTime() > 0)
                    run = false;
                if(left.getRunDistance() >= trackLength && left.getRunTime() == 0) {
                    left.setRunTime(seconds);
                    results.put(cars.size() - results.size(), left);
                }
                if(right.getRunDistance() >= trackLength && right.getRunTime() == 0) {
                    right.setRunTime(seconds);
                    results.put(cars.size() - results.size(), right);
                }
            }
            runNum++;
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Car> set : results.entrySet())
            System.out.println(set.getValue().getRunTime() + " seconds: " + set.getValue().getDriver() + " on " + set.getValue().getManufacturer() + " " + set.getValue().getModel());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно - это оформлять, используя разметку [JavaDoc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) )

Опишите назначение класса и все публичные методы, их параметры и возвращаемые значения.

> Метод setMaxSpeed невозращающий значения maxSpeed

Это не совсем правильно. То, что это метод под названием `setMaxSpeed`,  мы и так видим. А вот, что такое maxSpeed, никто не знает (как и формулировка "невозращающий значения"). Лучше было бы что-то вроде:

```
/** 
 *  Устанавливает значение максимальной скорости.
 */
```

А для getMaxSpeed соответственно:

```
/**
 *  Возвращает значение максимальной скорости.
 *  @return Максимальная скорость, если она задана, в противном случае -1
 */
```

(В вашем коде таких ограничений нет, я добавил для ясности)

Метод `main` документировать опять же нет смысла. Все программисты итак прекрасно знают, что это точка входа в программу.

> Статическая метод refresh невозращающий не какого значения с входными параметрами с условным оператором if

Тоже не слишком полезная формулировка. То что это статический метод видно и так, а то что у него внутри есть условный оператор нас вообще не должно волновать (представьте, что метод это черный ящик). Полезнее было бы описать общий принцип работы в сложном случае. И, конечно, крайне не хватает описания параметров `car` и `time`. Что это за машина, какое время нужно передавать? на эти вопросы должна кратко ответить javadoc. То есть на самом деле программист, который будет пользоваться этим кодом (например, вы через полгода) захочет прочитать что-то в духе:

```
/** 
 *  Обновляет состояние машины на указанный временной интервал.
 *
 *  При расчете учитывается длина трассы и максимальная скорость.
 *  @param car Обновляемая машина
 *  @param time Временной интервал относительно предыдущего состояния
 */
```

Главное: комментарии должны нести реально полезную информацию.

Answer (score 2):

полностью согласен с [[@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate)](/users/1984/nofate), все же кое-что добавлю от себя:

1) названия констант всегда в верхнем регистре. из-за того что с помошью регистра букв нет возможности отделять логические составляющие названия (сравните: trackLength и TRACKLENGTH), в константах используется знак подчеркивания.

```
private static final int trackLength = 402;

// а еще я группы констант отделяю такими комментариями на логические группы
// пример1: константы для автомобиля
...
// пример2: константы для трассы
private static final int TRACK_LENGTH = 402; // максимально-допустимая длина трека
```

^^ маленькая строчка поможет человеку разобратся для чего нужна эта константа

2) так уж сложилось что все методы с префиксом 'set' используются для того чтоб устанавливать какие-то свойства обьекта. несвойственно для java использовать его для других методов. да и нагрузки никакой смысловой его название сейчас не несет

```
private static void setCars() {} // установить автомобили?
private static void setUpCars() {} // настроить автомобили
private static void initialize()  // инициализация приложения (эта строчка должна быть в javadoc к методу)
{
    // проинициализировать автомобили
    initDefaultCars();

    // проинилиализировать что-то еще
    ...
}
```

последний вариант считаю самым оптимальным. он дает максимальное количество информации

3) метод main выглядит ужастно и абсолютно нечитаем. методы в особености перегруженные функционалом надо разбивать на логические секции. добавлять для каждой комментарий и отделять секции пустой строкой.

```
public class Dragracing
{

    private static Map < Integer, Car > cars = new HashMap < Integer, Car > () ;

    private static final int TRACK_LENGTH = 402 ;

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        // init application
        setCars () ;

        // обьявление переменных
        final HashMap < Integer, Car > results = new HashMap < Integer, Car > () ; // здесь храним результаты 
        int runNum = 1 ; // номер заезда

        // считаем что-то там для всех машин
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < cars.size () ; i++ )
        {
            // для теста используем две соседние? машины
            final Car right = new Car ( cars.get ( i ) ) ;
            final Car left = new Car ( cars.get ( i++ ) ) ;

            // выводим информацию о учасниках
            displayRaceStart ( runNum, left, right ) ;

            // подсчитываем результаты заезда
            int seconds = 0 ;
            boolean run = true ;
            while ( run )
            {
                // выводим текущее состояние
                displayRaceStatus ( runNum, left, right ) ;

                // пишем для чего увиличивается счетчик
                seconds++ ;

                // обновляем состояние автомобилей
                updateState ( left, seconds ) ;
                updateState ( right, seconds ) ;

                // проверяем условие остановки соревнования? (заменить на нужное)
                if ( (left.getRunTime () > 0) && (right.getRunTime () > 0) )
                {
                    run = false ;
                }

                // обновляем результаты гонки
                updateRaceResult ( results, left, seconds ) ;
                updateRaceResult ( results, right, seconds ) ;
            }

            // увиличиваем счетчик кругов? заездов?
            runNum++ ;
        }

        // выводим результаты гонки (коммент излишний? а не факт что в реальной програме будет только 1 строчка после него)
        displayRaceResults ( results ) ;
    }

    private static void displayRaceResults ( final HashMap < Integer, Car > results )
    {
        for ( final Map.Entry < Integer, Car > set : results.entrySet () )
        {
            System.out.println ( set.getValue ().getRunTime () + " seconds: " + set.getValue ().getDriver () + " on "
                    + set.getValue ().getManufacturer () + " " + set.getValue ().getModel () ) ;
        }
    }

    private static void displayRaceStart ( final int runNum, final Car a, final Car b )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Run " + runNum + ": " + a.getDriver () + " on " + a.getManufacturer () + " "
                + a.getModel () + " vs. " + b.getDriver () + " on " + b.getManufacturer () + " " + b.getModel () ) ;

        pause ( 3000 ) ;

        System.out.println ( "Ready!" ) ;
        pause ( 1000 ) ;

        System.out.println ( "Steady!" ) ;
        pause ( 1000 ) ;

        System.out.println ( "GO!" ) ;
    }

    private static void displayRaceStatus ( final int runNum, final Car left, final Car right )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Run " + runNum + ": " + left.getDriver () + " on " + left.getManufacturer () + " "
                + left.getModel () + " vs. " + right.getDriver () + " on " + right.getManufacturer () + " "
                + right.getModel () ) ;
        System.out.println ( left.getDriver () + ": " + left.getRunDistance () + " meters, " + left.getCurrentSpeed ()
                + " km/h" ) ;
        System.out.println ( right.getDriver () + ": " + right.getRunDistance () + " meters, "
                + right.getCurrentSpeed () + " km/h" ) ;

        pause ( 1000 ) ;
    }

    private static void pause ( final long delay )
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep ( delay ) ;
        }
        catch ( final InterruptedException e )
        {
            // failed sleep - ignore
        }
    }

    private static void refreshCarState ( final Car car, final int time )
    {
        final long maxSpeed = Math.round ( car.getMaxSpeed () / 3.6 ) ;
        long curSpeed = Math.round ( car.getVelocity () * time ) ;
        if ( curSpeed > maxSpeed )
        {
            curSpeed = maxSpeed ;
        }
        car.setRunDistance ( (car.getRunDistance () + curSpeed) > TRACK_LENGTH ? TRACK_LENGTH : car.getRunDistance ()
                + curSpeed ) ;
        car.setCurrentSpeed ( Math.round ( curSpeed * 3.6 ) ) ;
    }

    private static void setCars ()
    {
        cars.put ( 1, new Car ( 1, "Toyota", "Celica", 6, 250, "Alex" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 2, new Car ( 2, "Dodge", "Viper", 7, 310, "Steve" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 3, new Car ( 3, "Porsche", "911", 9, 320, "Martin" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 4, new Car ( 4, "Dodge", "Challenger", 9, 250, "Andrew" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 5, new Car ( 5, "Toyota", "MR2", 5, 250, "Jim" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 6, new Car ( 6, "Honda", "NSX", 8, 280, "Hiroki" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 7, new Car ( 7, "Chevrolet", "Camaro", 8, 270, "Ricky" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 8, new Car ( 8, "Nissan", "GTR", 8, 310, "Kito" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 9, new Car ( 9, "Lamborghini", "Countach", 8, 300, "Linda" ) ) ;
        cars.put ( 10, new Car ( 10, "VAZ", "2107", 8, 200, "Vasiliy" ) ) ;
    }

    private static void updateRaceResult ( final HashMap < Integer, Car > results, final Car car, final int seconds )
    {
        // race results updates when car finishes
        if ( (TRACK_LENGTH <= car.getRunDistance ()) && (0 == car.getRunTime ()) )
        {
            updateRaceResultImpl ( results, car, seconds ) ;
        }
    }

    private static void updateRaceResultImpl ( final HashMap < Integer, Car > results, final Car car, final int seconds )
    {
        // update car state
        car.setRunTime ( seconds ) ;

        // update results
        results.put ( Integer.valueOf ( cars.size () - results.size () ), car ) ;
    }

    private static void updateState ( final Car left, final int seconds )
    {
        if ( left.getRunTime () == 0 )
        {
            refreshCarState ( left, seconds ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > так уж сложилось что все методы с префиксом 'set' используются для ...

Я вас тут немного поправлю. Это не просто "сложилось", а вполне четкая концепция под названием JavaBeans, предусматривающая геттеры и сеттеры для свойств объекта.

Comment: я не совсем правильно выразился, я имел в виду что ограниченное использование методов с префиксом set в java является следствием того то вы написали. ведь javabeans/pojo никоим образом не устанавливают ограничения на названия других методов (где "других" подразумевается любых методов кроме геттеров/сеттеров - get/set/is )